# Writing dictionaries to Sql table, Code is getting executed without any issues but the values are not getting binded into the SQL table

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code is to write the Nested Dictionaries into SQL table.

Code is getting executed without any issues, But the values are not getting binded into the SQL table.

Can anyone check & tell what is the problem in my code.

Thanks in advance

```
import mysql.connector as conn

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00")

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    database = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details ( User_ID VARCHAR(255), Name VARCHAR(255), Age VARCHAR(255), Occupation VARCHAR(255), Department VARCHAR(255), Salary VARCHAR(255), Address VARCHAR(255) ) ")

user_details = {}

while True:
    user_input = input(" You're Operation Please ( New / View ) Details : ").lower()

    if user_input == 'new':
        create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
        user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
        user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
        user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age
        user_occupation = input(" Enter the users occupation : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Occupation'] = user_occupation
        user_department = input(" user department : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Department'] = user_department
        user_income = int(input(" Enter the salary details : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Salary'] = user_income
        user_address = input(" Enter the Address details ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Address'] = user_address

        print(f" New User account {create_user_ID} has been successfully created")
        for detail in user_details.items():
            print(detail)

        for k,v in user_details.items():
            user_col = k
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Details (User_ID) VALUES ("%s")' % (user_col))

            for v_1 in user_details.values():
                cols = v_1.keys()
                vals = v_1.values()

                sql = "INSERT INTO Details ({}) VALUES ({})".format(
                ', '.join(cols),
                ', '.join(['%s'] * len(cols)));

                cursor.execute(sql, list(vals))

        process = input(" Do you want to continue the Account creation process (YES / NO ) : ").lower()
        if process == 'no':
            break

    elif user_input == 'view':
        break

    else:
        print(" Please enter the proper command to execute (new / view)")
```

Code is getting executed without any issues, But the values are not getting binded into the SQL table.

Can anyone check & tell what is the problem in my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the cursor.commit() method to commit your changes on the database.